# using dotnetnuke (dnn) with with subversion

Tags: asp.net, svn, dotnetnuke

Currently i am developing sites using DNN framework. Currently my development and staging environment is same. Client is vewing same site which I am using for development.

I have started using tortoise svn (subversion) for maintaining versions and backup. I am using file based svn repository for it.

The issue is svn creates .svn folder (hidden) in every folder. This folder and files inside it shows in portal system while file selection and at many different locations like FCKEditor File Browser, Icon selection for module / page, skins selection.

I would like to hide this folder for entire application and it should not show up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have the same environment for development and staging? I would really recommend against it. Even if you have them on the same server, I think you should have them at least in separate virtual directories.

Assuming you have then done that, it is simple to keep the '.' directories hidden, you simply `export` your svn repository from dev to staging. Staging will no longer be a working copy so the '.' directories will not be present. This also allows to test potentially breaking changes without affecting the client and it keeps the staging environment more stable.

Comment: I am sharing development envrionment with client cause of constant change request and to minimize overall time to add new features. the final set of change are exported and applied to hosted environment where site is visible for general use.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the .svn folders in DNN but you'll have to modify the core.

Probably an easier solution is to exclude the folder Portals/[PortalID] from your repository, but that depends on what you're developing. Do you need the Portal's files in your repository?

Comment: yes i need portal files too, as this is also working as backup system

Comment: If you need other files, for backup purposes, since the database file is needed as well, I would recommend taking the backups out of the source control process.

Comment: WE would like to take backups with versioning in place, like new site will be one of the versin. As both core modules modifications and site creations and maintainance (new site added inside portal folder) needs version control. I am combining both.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if you are NOT modifying the core of DNN, I wouldn't check in the core system, and only your custom modules, skins etc.

Comment: We would like to take backups with versioning in place, like new site will be one of the verson. As both core modules modifications and site creations and maintainance (new site added inside portal folder) needs version control. I am combining both.